# Small blogging script

Tags: python, object-oriented

I've recently re-written a Python script I use to run a couple of lightweight blogs. Looking over the horrible code I'd written before, I decided to rewrite it using object-oriented concepts. I wanted to submit it to get feedback, best practices, and other areas I should look at. This is my first script that uses any object oriented ideas.

```
import markdown
import jinja2
import re
import datetime
import time
import glob
import cgi

class Article:
    def __init__(self, local_dir, local_file):
        local_file = local_file.replace('/','')
        self.local_file_name = local_file
        with open(local_dir + '/' + local_file) as f:
            self.lines = f.readlines()
        self.file_text = ''.join(self.lines[4:])        

    def text(self):
        return self.file_text

    def title(self):
        title = self.get_metadata(self.lines[0])
        return title

    def html_filename(self):
        html_filename = re.sub('.txt','.html',self.local_file_name)
        return html_filename

    def date_text(self):
        date_text = self.get_metadata(self.lines[2])
        return date_text

    def date_datetime(self):
        date_txt = self.date_text()
        date_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_txt, '%d %B %Y')
        return date_obj

    def date_rss(self):
        date = time.strptime(self.date_text(), '%d %B %Y')
        rss_date = time.strftime('%a, %d %b %Y 06:%M:%S +0000', date)
        return rss_date

    def summary(self):
        summary = re.sub('<[^<]+?>','', self.html())[0:200]
        summary = re.sub('\n',' ',summary)
        return summary

    def html(self):
        md = markdown.Markdown()
        converted_text = md.convert(self.file_text).encode('utf-8')
        return converted_text

    def get_metadata(self,line):
        element = re.sub('\n|Author: |Date: |Title: ','',line)
        element = cgi.escape(element).strip()
        return element

class FileList:
    def __init__(self, dir, ignore_list):
        self.textfiles = glob.glob(dir+"/*.txt")
        for ignored_file in ignore_list:
            self.textfiles.remove(dir+ignored_file)

    def files(self):
        return self.textfiles

class Site:
    def load_articles(self, dir, ignore_list):
        file_list = FileList(dir, ignore_list)
        articles = []
        for file in file_list.files():
            article = Article(dir, file.replace(dir,''))
            articles.append({
                    'title': article.title(),
                    'datetime': article.date_datetime(),
                    'text': article.text(),
                    'summary': article.summary(),
                    'html': article.html(), 
                    'date_text': article.date_text(),
                    'html_filename': article.html_filename(),
                    'date_rss': article.date_rss()
                    },)
        articles = sorted(articles, key=lambda k: k['datetime'], reverse=True)
        return articles

    def build_from_template(self, data, template, output_file, dir):
        with open(template) as f:
            template = jinja2.Template(f.read())
        with open(dir + '/' + output_file,'w') as i:
            i.write(template.render(data = data))
        return True

    def build_site(self, params):
        dir = params['DIR']
        template_dir = params['TEMPLATE_DIR']
        index_template = template_dir + '/index_template.html'
        archive_template = template_dir + '/archive_template.html'
        rss_template = template_dir + '/rss_template.xml'
        article_template = template_dir + '/article_template.html'
        index_output = '/index.html'
        archive_output = '/archive.html'
        rss_output = '/index.xml'       
        site = Site()
        articles = site.load_articles(dir, params['IGNORE_LIST'])       
        for article in articles:
            output = article['html_filename']
            site.build_from_template(article, article_template, output, dir)
        site.build_from_template(articles, index_template, index_output, dir)
        site.build_from_template(articles, archive_template, archive_output, dir)
        site.build_from_template(articles, rss_template, rss_output, dir)   
        return True
```

Here's the script that executes the code above to actually build a site:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python

import pueblo

PARAMS = {
    'DIR': '/dir/to/your/html/files/', # no final slash
    'TEMPLATE_DIR': '/dir/to/store/your/templates', # no final slash
    'IGNORE_LIST': ['ignorethis.txt']
    }

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"

site = pueblo.Site()
site.build_site(PARAMS)

print "<html><head><title>Site Rebuilt</title></head><body><h1>Site Rebuilt</h1></body></html>"
```

Finally, here's an example Jinja2 template:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>yoursite.com</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=yes, width=device-width" />
<link href="./index.xml" rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" />
<h1>yoursite.com</h1>
<p class="site_description">your description</p>
<ul class="navbar">
<li class="navitem"><a href="your_about_page.html">about</a></li>
<li class="navitem"><a href="./archive.html">archive</a></li>
</ul></div>
<div class="article_list">
{% for i in range(30) %}
<h2><a href="{{ data[i].html_filename }}">{{ data[i].title }}</a></h2>
<p>{{ data[i].date_text }}: {{ data[i].summary }} <a href="{{ data[i].html_filename }}">...</a></p>
{% endfor %}
<h2><a href="archive.html">View All Articles</a></h2>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import markdown
import jinja2
import re
import datetime
import time
import glob
import cgi

class Article:
    def __init__(self, local_dir, local_file):
```

It would make more sense to pass in the complete path, and then use `os.path.dirname` and `os.path.basename` to extract the parts if you need them.

```
        local_file = local_file.replace('/','')
```

Don't use replace to eliminate items in your string if you know where they are. Use `.lstrip()` or `.rstrip()` to remove from the beginning or end. Furthermore, don't use string manipulation on filepaths at all. Use `os.path` functions

```
        self.local_file_name = local_file
```

Don't store things in local variables and then store them on the object. Just store them directly on the object.

```
        with open(local_dir + '/' + local_file) as f:
            self.lines = f.readlines()
        self.file_text = ''.join(self.lines[4:])        

    def text(self):
        return self.file_text
```

Rather then define functions like this, just store it as `.text` and fetch it directly.

```
    def title(self):
        title = self.get_metadata(self.lines[0])
        return title

    def html_filename(self):
        html_filename = re.sub('.txt','.html',self.local_file_name)
        return html_filename
```

Don't use regular expressions when a simple string function will do the same. In this case `.` means something special and so this probably doesn't work exactly like you think.

```
    def date_text(self):
        date_text = self.get_metadata(self.lines[2])
        return date_text

    def date_datetime(self):
        date_txt = self.date_text()
        date_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_txt, '%d %B %Y')
        return date_obj

    def date_rss(self):
        date = time.strptime(self.date_text(), '%d %B %Y')
        rss_date = time.strftime('%a, %d %b %Y 06:%M:%S +0000', date)
        return rss_date
```

Generally, it doesn't make sense to have an object provide its data in multiple formats like this. Just provide access to the datetime object. Your caller can use the `strftime/strptime` methods to get the format they want. It doesn't make any sense for this object to be concerned with the formats other objects want.

```
    def summary(self):
        summary = re.sub('<[^<]+?>','', self.html())[0:200]
```

We use +? instead of *?

```
        summary = re.sub('\n',' ',summary)
        return summary



    def html(self):
        md = markdown.Markdown()
        converted_text = md.convert(self.file_text).encode('utf-8')
        return converted_text
```

I'd suggest for all these, that you extract the data in the constructor, and store it on local attributes.

```
    def get_metadata(self,line):
        element = re.sub('\n|Author: |Date: |Title: ','',line)
```

This ignores the actual information saying what the line is. That bothers me. I think it'd better to follow those pieces of information.

```
        element = cgi.escape(element).strip()
        return element

class FileList:
    def __init__(self, dir, ignore_list):
        self.textfiles = glob.glob(dir+"/*.txt")
        for ignored_file in ignore_list:
            self.textfiles.remove(dir+ignored_file)

    def files(self):
        return self.textfiles
```

Again, no need in python to define getters, just access the attributes. The whole thing actually would be better as a function return the list of files.

```
class Site:
    def load_articles(self, dir, ignore_list):
        file_list = FileList(dir, ignore_list)
        articles = []
        for file in file_list.files():
            article = Article(dir, file.replace(dir,''))
            articles.append({
                    'title': article.title(),
                    'datetime': article.date_datetime(),
                    'text': article.text(),
                    'summary': article.summary(),
                    'html': article.html(), 
                    'date_text': article.date_text(),
                    'html_filename': article.html_filename(),
                    'date_rss': article.date_rss()
                    },)
```

Don't copy your article over into a dictionary. That completely defeats the point of having object. Make a list of articles and have Jinja extract the fields.

```
        articles = sorted(articles, key=lambda k: k['datetime'], reverse=True)
```

Why not do an inplace sort?

```
        return articles

    def build_from_template(self, data, template, output_file, dir):
        with open(template) as f:
            template = jinja2.Template(f.read())
        with open(dir + '/' + output_file,'w') as i:
            i.write(template.render(data = data))
        return True

    def build_site(self, params):
        dir = params['DIR']
        template_dir = params['TEMPLATE_DIR']
        index_template = template_dir + '/index_template.html'
        archive_template = template_dir + '/archive_template.html'
        rss_template = template_dir + '/rss_template.xml'
        article_template = template_dir + '/article_template.html'
        index_output = '/index.html'
        archive_output = '/archive.html'
        rss_output = '/index.xml'       
        site = Site()
```

You already have a site object, why are you creating another one?

```
        articles = site.load_articles(dir, params['IGNORE_LIST'])       
        for article in articles:
            output = article['html_filename']
            site.build_from_template(article, article_template, output, dir)
        site.build_from_template(articles, index_template, index_output, dir)
        site.build_from_template(articles, archive_template, archive_output, dir)
        site.build_from_template(articles, rss_template, rss_output, dir)
```

You repeat the same thing for the index/archive/rss without any substational code differences. Have a list of `["archive","rss",index"]` and do everything related to those in a loop.

```
        return True
```

Serves no purpuse. You don't need a return value unless you are answering a question.

Comment: Thank you very much for this, Winston. Can you describe the in-place sort? I'm not exactly sure how that would work when I don't have a list of articles somewhere ordered by the datetime.

Comment: @MikeShea, use the `.sort()` method instead of the `sorted()` function. Its somewhat more efficient if you don't need to keep the original list.

Comment: Thanks! I just updated it with articles.sort(key=lambda k: k.datetime, reverse=True) instead of articles = sorted(articles, blah). A big help!

Answer (score 4):

Overall your design looks good to me. A couple of relatively minor things to note:

**Use new-style classes**
In Python 2.x you should make sure your classes inherit from `object`. Such classes are known as new-style classes. (In Python 3.x all classes are new-style classes.) New-style classes offer:

- support for the built-in function `super()` to refer to the base class (or other parent class) without hard-coding; more info: http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/
- improved method resolution order (MRO); more info: http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/06/method-resolution-order.html
- support for descriptors: methods that behave like attributes; more info: http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#invoking-descriptors

**Use the standard-library to make your code more portable**
When building up paths you may do so in a cross-platform way by using `os.path.join`. This is just one example, but there are other places in your code where you can use this:

```
import os
file_path = os.path.join( local_dir, local_file )
with open(file_path) as f:
    ...
```

**Miscellaneous**
There is a comment which doesn't agree with the code.

```
'DIR': '/dir/to/your/html/files/', # no final slash
```

Comment: Is this a simple matter of doing something like "class article(object):"?

Comment: Yes exactly: `class Article(object):`

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with [directly accessing class attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8297723/oop-getter-setter-methods) in Python, so you could cut out some complexity by doing all your metadata-related calculation once in `__init__`:

```
class Article:
    def __init__(self, local_dir, local_file):
        ...
        # I'd actually lose get_metadata() completely, and do its list parsing here as well.
        self.title = self.get_metadata(self.lines[0])
        self.html_filename = re.sub('.txt','.html',self.local_file_name)           
        # etc.
```

If the attribute is something that's likely to need some manipulation each time you need it, you can use properties as well.

Also, as a general note, you don't really need to assign your return values to a variable before returning them. You can easily do

```
def title(self):
    return self.get_metadata(self.lines[0])
```

instead of

```
def title(self):
    title = self.get_metadata(self.lines[0])
    return title
```